# how to control delete in django_admin

Tags: django, django-admin

i would like to control when it's possible to delete elements in django admin. 
first, i tried to override the delete method of models to raise integrity error. it's work but this exception in not catch by admin and don't show a nice message. in fact, if you run in production mode, all that it say is " a problem has occurred".

secondly, i put a form and the clean method. it don't work either. the clean method is run whenever you modify the element. not only when you delete.

so how to have a way to control deleting of element in django admin (and have a nice message saying why you can't delete it )?

Answer (score 0):

No need, to show a message, the delete buttons won't show as long you use this:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    ...
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```